# How can I see more output lines in terminal?

Tags: terminal, history, terminator

If I give a command that has a lot of output lines in terminal, about 400, I can only see the last ~200 if I scroll up to the top. How can I go further up and see more output lines? I don't want to use tee and copy the output to a text file. I use Openbox and Terminator.

How can I see the terminal output from two days ago?

Answer (score 44):

Terminator's configuration (including buffer size), is stored in its configuration file, usually found at `~/.config/terminator/config`.

You may configure the buffer size by modifying the configuration file to include the following.  Be sure to include the section headings, as these are necessary.

```
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    scrollback_lines = 5000
```

Reference: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/terminator_config.5.html

---

You may also modify Terminator configuration by right-clicking in a Terminator window, and selecting `Preferences`.  The relevant preference is in `Profiles > Default > Scrolling > Scrollback`.

Comment: If your right click is used for paste like mine, shift+MiddleClick gets you the preference menu.

Answer (score 9):

*I had to do this in the **terminal preferences** for Ubuntu 14.04*

## Edit > Profile Preferences > Scrolling > Scrollback:

I set mine to 2048 (512 is default), close, restart terminal

Answer (score 7):

You may want infinite scrollback:

In `~/.config/terminator/config`:

```
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    scrollback_infinite = True
```

Answer (score 3):

You could pipe the output to more (or less) and page through the results.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the scrollback buffer size in ~/.config/terminator, e.g.:

```
scrollback_lines = 5000
```

This will set the buffer size to 5000 lines.

Comment: ~/.config/terminator/config is missing. I tried to reinstall terminator but it's still not there.

Comment: @tr3quart1sta: Just create it with that content, then.

Comment: Also, in Gnome, you open a terminal, select the drop down menu -> Preferences->blq blq and on one of the tabs there is a dialog box, asking how many wines to remember. The default 256 is ridiculous !